# ¿Cómo eliminar cadena que empiece con "A" en una pila en c#?

Tags: c#, pilas

Este es mi método que me debería poder eliminar la cadena que comience con "A", pero tengo el problema que al ejecutarlo me da error en el if, lo que necesito saber es como puedo hacer par que en if no me de el error de tipos de datos de que no se puede pasar de string a char, no soy muy experimentado y por ello es que tengo algunas dificultades.

Este ejercicio lo he estado haciendo simulación de pila, y por ello es que no hago uso de los métodos de c#.

De ante mano gracias por la ayuda.

```
static void Eliminar_A(ref Pila po, int n)
    {
        Pila pt = new Pila();
        pt.Cdato(n);
        Start(ref pt);
        string dato = "";
        while (!Empty(po))
        {
            Pop(ref po, ref dato);
            if (dato[0] != 'A' || dato[0] != 'a')
                Push(ref pt, dato, n);
        }
        while (!Empty(pt))
        {
            Pop(ref pt, ref dato);
            Push(ref po, dato, n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saludos. Dado que **dato** es un **string** te sugiero evalues si **inicia con** (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0) u obteniendo el primer caracter (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0) cuestión del enfoque que le quieras dar.

Answer (score 2):

Puede que sea porque la cadena esté vacía y por tanto te dé un error, prueba con ésto:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dato) && (dato[0] != 'A' || dato[0] != 'a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Como bien plantea Jose Antonio Bautista el error puede deberse a que la cadena `dato`, este vacia, por eso una solución seria la que el plantea:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dato) && (dato[0] != 'A' || dato[0] != 'a'))
```

Pero quiero agregar, que aun cuando no es el problema planteado en tu pregunta, en tu código hay un error de logica; si lo que deseas es que de tu código debería poder eliminar la cadena que comience con "A" o con "a", es decir eliminar las cadenas que inician con "A" ya sea minuscula o mayuscula, la condición planteada `(dato[0] != 'A' || dato[0] != 'a')` no se corresponde con la logica de lo que deseas hacer; pues la condición `if` se cumplirá siempre que se cumpla cualquiera de las dos condiciones del operador OR `||` y es obvio que siempre se cumplira una de las dos, por tanto agregará a la pila `pt` todas las cadenas, la condición congruente con la logica del problema que deseas seria usar el operador AND `&&` de la siguiente forma.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dato) && (dato[0] != 'A' && dato[0] != 'a'))
```

Es decir, solo se cumpliria la condicional `if` cuando se cumpla que la cadena no inicia ni con "A" minuscula ni mayuscula.

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa simplificando la expresion:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dato) && dato[0].ToUpper() != 'A')
```